# Update SqlDataSource SelectCommand Client Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is my first attempt at building my own website so apologies in advance if this is a silly question..

I have a gridview which is populated from a `SqlDataSource`. I also have a control which has `AutopostBack=True` to update the gridview based on the contents of the control after update.

The code I have so far is (I've changed real field names!)

**testPage.aspx:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"   
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Lookup"   
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">  
    <Columns>  
        //Column headings removed for clarity 
    </Columns>  
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Field1], [Field2], 
[Field3], [Field4], [Field5], [Field6], [Field7], [Field8] FROM [Analysis] 
 ORDER BY [Field1], [Field2] DESC, [Field3] DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**testPage.aspx.cs:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (ctl04.Value == null)
            {
                SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Field1], [Field2], 
                [Field3], [Field4], [Field5], [Field6], [Field7], [Field8] 
                FROM [Analysis] ORDER BY [Field1], [Field2] DESC, [Field3] 
                DESC";
            }
            else
            {
                SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Field1], [Field2], 
                [Field3], [Field4], [Field5], [Field6], [Field7], [Field8] 
                FROM [Analysis] WHERE [Lookup] IN ('" +   
                ctl04.Text.ToString().Replace(",","','") + "') ORDER BY 
                [Field1], [Field2] DESC, [Field3] DESC";

            }
            gridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

So far this works great when testing. However, what I'm unsure about is if say there are multiple users using this page does this cause problems because it's running server side. Eg if 1 user updates the control, does every other user also see that selection in the gridView when first going to the page?

Can anyone give some pointers on how to make this work client side only so selections in the control don't affect other users?

Comment: what do you  mean by updates control? Also remove dupicate calls to gridview1.Databind in your code behind.

Comment: If user1 updates the control `ctl04`, does it change the `SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand` for just user1 or all users? If there are 20 users changing at the same time, does it become a race where no-one can view their change to the control in the gridView as other users keep changing theirs?

Comment: It will just change for that user for sure.

Comment: You could have not asked if you were aware of it :) But thats ok to ask silly questions. No one is perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if 1 user updates the control, does every other user also see that
>   selection in the gridView when first going to the page?

**NO**

ASP.net render new pages for each user, changing select command by one user not affect to other users. if you get select command from database or shared file etc.. and update that by one user will see the changes by all others